# ability to search for a specific value in a JSON in apex

Tags: apex, json

Sample JSON below

```
[
   {
      "OrderNumber": 12345,
      "OrderLineReference": "190828-11-VWT-5653090001001",
      "Addition": "0,00",
      "Axis": 60,
      "Cylinder": 100,
      "Eye": "Right",
      "Sphere": "123",
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Product": "466772 P. UF1.5 UV SOL N3 / 146772",
      "Supplements": "663 Digipack- - -"
   },
   {
      "OrderNumber": 12345,
      "OrderLineReference": "190828-11-VWT-5653090001002",
      "Addition": "0,00",
      "Axis": -1,
      "Cylinder": "0",
      "Eye": "Left",
      "Sphere": "111",
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Product": "466772 P. UF1.5 UV SOL N3 / 146772",
      "Supplements": "663 Digipack- - -"
   },
   {
      "OrderNumber": 12345,
      "OrderLineReference": "190828-11-VWT-5653090001F001",
      "Product": "OWIS095 C01 BLACK 55x18x140"
   }
]
```

I have a search component that searches for a JSON. Is it possible to search by specific value? Ex. I'll search for a **sphere** with the value '111' then it will display only Sphere with value '111'?

Thank you all.

Comment: Few questions Are, Is this data comes from outside from Salesforce, If this data present in salesforce, I think you should go with SOQL with where condition. else you are already building component So you should do search functionality at the client-side mean in component JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Parse the JSON using one of these [JSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) methods. (One way to do that is via the code generated by https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/.) Then loop over the items checking the `Sphere` value.

Comment: thank you kind sir.